# PHP - How to avoid "echo" HTML when there is a need for conditional html blocks for example

Tags: php, javascript, html, echo

Echoing HTML blocks in PHP is a pain, The echoed parts are not properly marked and parsed by IDE's since it's a string. This deficiency makes it very difficult to properly edit and change echoed html (especially with JavaScript).
I wonder if there is an elegant solution except for using include in such cases.

Comment: If you are needing large blocks of html you can just write it outside of the ?> <?php blocks

Comment: For blocks of code in PHP business logic, you can store PHP in external snippets and load them in when you need them. For JavaScript, perhaps a JS template engine will help (e.g. [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another example using an alternative if-Syntax:

```
<?php if($a == 5): ?>
<p>A=5</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you don't need to echo just close PHP tags , e.g:

```
<ul>
<?php 
foreach($foo as $bar) {
?>
  <li> hi i'm <?=$bar;?> </li> 
<?
}
?>
</ul>
```

EDIT:

for even more readability (often used in MVC views + wordpress type systems) omit the curly braces:

```
<ul>
<?php 
foreach($foo as $bar):
?>
  <li> hi i'm <?=$bar;?> </li> 
<?
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was just about to mention the colon approach for view layers - but you beat me to it with your edit. Good stuff! You'll need to swap `$bar` to `<?php echo $bar ?>` of course though.

Answer (score 1):

Just close and reopen the PHP tags

```
<?php
//blah blah PHP code
$title = 'My title';
?>
<section>
    <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
</section>
<?php
//More PHP code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open and close PHP tags (`<?php ?>`) whenever you want:

```
<?php    
//php code    
?>

<!-- html goes here -->    

<?php    
//php code again    
?>
```